# Two fingers pan\touch down

Tags: java, libgdx, multi-touch

I need to implement the following functionality, the left side of the screen implements Pan gesture, the right side - a long press or touch down. If these two methods are implemented separately, then everything is fine. But if at the same time try to make touch down and pan, then all the blocking, the two do not work. Try do all things through InputMultiplekser and the like, but it does not work anyway.
Prompt how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `boolean` flags - you cannot touch at the same moment.
Example:

```
if(touchDown){
   return;    //Exit the function
}
pan = true;

//inside the touch down function:
if(pan){
   return;
}
touchDown = true;
```

Note that, you have to add `pan = false`, when 'panning' is complete, etc.

I hope it helps!

staticcasty